# How to get included LaTeX rendered properly in Pandoc PDF output?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

Using the following two files:

- `tst.md`

  ````
  ---
  title: Test case for `pandoc-include` LaTeX bug.
  author: David Banas <capn.freako@gmail.com>
  date: July 9, 2020
  ...

  $$
  E = m c^2
  $$

  ```include
  inc.md
  ```
  ````
- `inc.md`:

  ```
  $$
  E = m c^2
  $$
  ```

I get the following, in response to the given `pandoc` commands:

- `pandoc -f markdown+smart+tex_math_dollars -o tst.pdf -s --mathjax --filter pandoc-include tst.md`

  [image: Pandoc PDF Output]
- `pandoc -f markdown+smart+tex_math_dollars -o tst.html -s --mathjax --filter pandoc-include tst.md`

  [image: Pandoc HTML Output]

And I'm wondering: why does the included LaTeX get rendered properly in the HTML version, but not in the PDF version?

Comment: Perhaps ecause you're using MathJax. Pandoc just outputs the math as `$`-enclosed Latex and lets MathJax render it, which it does by searching your HTML document for `$`-enclosed Latex. Depending on how this is viewed, this issue could rather be that Pandoc isn't properly escaping the `$` in the HTML case?

Answer (score 0):

The filter seems to be unaware of the input format; it always assumes plain markdown with only the most basic extensions, and without the `tex_math_dollars` extension.

To dive a bit deeper: looking at the [code](https://github.com/steindani/pandoc-include/blob/master/IncludeFilter.hs#L70-L71) we see that `readMarkdown` is called with the `def` default reader options

```hs
ioReadMarkdown :: String -> IO(Either PandocError Pandoc)
ioReadMarkdown content = return $! readMarkdown def content
```

but should probably be called with the default pandoc extensions for Markdown `(def { readerExtensions = pandocExtensions })`.

@amon accurately describes the reason for the PDF/HTML difference in their comment:

> Pandoc just outputs the math as `$`-enclosed Latex and lets MathJax render it,
> which it does by searching your HTML document for `$`-enclosed Latex.